# Little bit misunderstanding with datetime formats

Tags: oracle, datetime-format, oracle12c

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-10-01 01:00:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

Gives : `2016-10-01 01:00:01`

Here `year` and `month` parts are understood for me, but [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210) says about other formats:

`"DD" - Day of month (1-31)`

`"HH24" - Hour of day (0-23)`

`"MI" - Minute (0-59)`

`"SS" - Second (0-59)`

So, why for example "DD" format returns `01` and not just: `1` ?

For example "MM" format, in same doc described as:

`MM - Month (01-12; January = 01)` and here everything clearly: January = **01** .

Also, little bit confusing is time parts (for me at least) , because in documentation, range for all  begins with `0` but returns result as `00`

I've expected from above query, result like this:

`2016-10-1 1:0:1`

What I missed and don't understood correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are passing in two strings: the actual datetime (or timestamp) you want to convert to timestamp datatype, and the format model. Then you call `to_timestamp()`, and the result is a timestamp. Then you DISPLAY this on screen (through SQLPlus or SQL Developer or whatever). Only strings can be displayed on screen - not numbers, not timestamps, etc. So: somewhere, somehow, your timestamp is converted back to a string.

You either do that explicitly, by calling `to_char(.....)` around your timestamp, or if you don't, the interface application (SQLPlus, SQL Developer, ...) uses your session's `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` parameter. In that parameter, you can force whatever format model you want. In particular, you can suppress leading zeros with the `FM` format model modifier.

Without changing your `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` you can see the same effect by using `to_char()` in the query. Try this:

```
select to_char(to_date('01-Feb-12', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'FMdd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;
```

Output:   `1/2/2012 0:0:0`